# G++ default search path

Tags: g++, ubuntu-11.04

Where can be found default settings for search path for headers in Ubuntu 11.04? This is for g++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_21.html):

> By default, `gcc` searches the following directories for header files:
>
> ```
>      /usr/include
>      /usr/local/include
> ```

Answer (score 2):

This may be useful:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/cpp/Search-Path.html#Search-Path

Comment: <quote> You can add to this list with the -Idir command line option. All the directories named by -I are searched, in left-to-right order, before the default directories. The only exception is when dir is already searched by default. In this case, the option is ignored and the search order for system directories remains unchanged. </quote>

Answer (score 1):

gcc also recognizes -isysroot where you specify the root of your header and other files

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options